# Is it possible to create a template in Word 2010 that will print the cover page on a different size of paper?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, templates

I'm creating a new template for an 8.5x11 document, but I want the cover page to be printed on 11x17, so I can fold the cover page over document like a book cover, with the cover page printed on the front.

Is this doable? If so, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought it would be.

When you create a section break then you can change the paper size and layout for each section.

All I had to do was create a break that started the section on the new page, then change the first page's layout to 11x17 landscape, and made two columns with the margins adjusted so I could have a cover page and a back.